# Get nosetests configuration options

Tags: python, configuration, nosetests

I want to get some options from the nose configuration file.
But I don't want to parse the file by myself, so I try to use the nose [api](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/api/config.html)

I'm not sure how to interpret the information mentioned on this side:

```
import nose

def setup()
  noseParser = nose.config.Config().getParser()
  value = noseParser.get_option("debug-log")
```

That's the way I think it should work. But `value` keeps being `None` and no exception is raised.

My usecase: Delete the debug-log file each time nose is running.

Answer (score 1):

According to link you've provided getParser() returns '**command line** option parser'. I'm not sure but you could check what `nose.config.Config().debugLog` is set to.

Comment: It indeed returns the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the nose code, I don't see a clear API to get the options from the configuration files. What I see is that:

- You can get the configuration files from `nose.config.all_config_files()` and `nose.config.user_config_files()`.
- nose it's not using any custom parsing class, but just `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser`.

Hence, maybe isn't such a bad idea to parse the configuration files directly after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best approach is to [write a custom plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html#writing-plugins).  That way, you let nose do the work for you.  It sounds like what you want to do is delete the `debug-log` after all tests have been run.  To do that, you'd need a plugin that implements the finalize() method.  In this example, I also implemented the options() so that the plugin can be enabled/disabled and configure(), to find the location of the debug-log.  [Check out the full list of methods here](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html#plugin-interface-methods).

```
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import os

class AutoDeleteDebugLog(Plugin):
    """
    Automatically deletes the error log after test execution.  This may not be
    wise, so think carefully.
    """
    def options(self, parser, env):
        "Register commandline options using Nose plugin API."
        parser.add_option('--with-autodeletedebuglog', action='store_true',
                          help='Delete the debug log file after execution.')
        self.debuglog = None

    def configure(self, options, conf):
        "Register commandline options using Nose plugin API."
        self.enabled = options.autodeletedebuglog
        self.debuglog = options.debugLog

    def finalize(self, result):
        "Delete debug log file after all results are printed."
        if os.path.isfile(self.debuglog):
            os.remove(self.debuglog)
```

Once you write your plug-in, you'll have to register it with nose, and enable it at execution time.  There [are instructions for that here](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html#registering).  You may also want to play with the `score` attribute to ensure that your plugin is run last.